# How do I only call \maketitle if \title{} has been called

Tags: titles, conditionals

I'm merging 5-10 `pandoc` generated tex files using the `docmute` package. The individual files build, however when I `\subimport` or `\input` them into my main document I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No \title given
```

This is because everything outside the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` is stripped by `docmute`, so `\title{}` is not called for the individual documents when merging. Actually, I don't want to call `\maketitle` at all for the merged documents.

How can I conditionally use `maketitle`? I've tried various `\if` combinations, including things like:

```
\ifdef{\@title}{\maketitle}{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial state of `\@title` is not that it is undefined, it is defined by

```
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
```

so you want

```
\makeatletter
\def\zz@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}

\ifx\zz@title\@title
% do nothing
\else
\maketitle
\fi

\makeatother
```